# PHP Email is not sent but result is true

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail

I am using following code to send email from a **windows server**

```
$message = "Email From Sami";
$to = 'myid@gmail.com';
$subject = " test colr";
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$mail=mail($to, $subject,$message );
if($mail)
{
    echo "Thank you for using our mail form"; // I am getting this message
}
else
{
    echo "Mail sending failed."; 
}
```

But neither I am getting any error nor email is being received at target email (I have tried different target email addresses).

I have set `smtp=localhost` and `port=25` in php.ini already. On the same server mail is being sent successfully from iis (Microsoft server). But **getting no error or result from php mail**

Comment: have you checked in spam/junk

Comment: Yes i had.. again and again :(.. On all target email addresses